# Is there a bridge for sending Kafka Data to AMQP / MQTT?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp

is there an bridge which can send data from a kafka topic to amqp(rabbitmq) or mqtt ?

I just find only the from mqtt/amqp to kafka but not backwards...

BR,

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Stimzi supplies a Kafka AMQP 1.0 bridge that could be used for such a task.  The project source is located on Github [here](https://github.com/strimzi/amqp-kafka-bridge) so I'd suggest starting there and reading the documentation.